# How to convert comma separated data to CopyOnWriteArrayList to be sent as payload in MUnit

Tags: java, mule, munit

I am implementing MUnit for a flow where I need to send the payload through a Set Message Processor as a CopyOnWriteArrayList. The payload data would be fetched from a file.

The file would have comma separated XML Data. I need this data to be sent as CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Please help me on the Java class that can be used in MEL.

Please find below updated details :

For the MUnit test, I have the data in a file as of the format [First_XML_Data,Second_XML_Data]. The First_XML_Data and Second_XML_Data are both XML data. So basically first component in mule flow is Java transformer as below:

public class XMLData extends AbstractTransformer {

```
@Override
protected Object doTransform(Object src, String enc) throws TransformerException {

        CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> list = (CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>) src;

}
```

}

As you can see, I need to prepare a payload in Set Message Processor so that it can be passed on to this Java transformer. So as of now I have the following MEL in set message processor of MUnit test,

## [Arrays.asList((getResource('src/main/resources/xml_data.xml').asString().split(',')))]

The applications throws a type cast exception. So i need to some how send the payload as CopyOnWriteArrayList. As the data is too large , I am picking it up from the File

Thanks.

Comment: What part of the problem are you having issues with?

Comment: What is comma separated XML data?  It sounds like a contradiction in terms.

Comment: The payload that has to be sent for processing should be a CopyOnWriteArrayList type. The data is too large. Hence I am picking it up from a file through a MUnit matcher in MEL. So is there any way I can handle/convert the data in file (present as comma separated xml data) to CopyOnWriteArrayList

Comment: 1) What I am asking is **what part** of the problem is giving you problems?  In other words, what have you tried.  2) Please reply to my second comment too.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and your current code of munit and flow?

Comment: Stephen and Manik... Please find the data updated in the question. This would help you understand the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use `Arrays.asList()`, you should construct the [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

```
#[new java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList(getResource('src/main/resources/xml_data.xml').asString().split(','))]
```